# fireSQL initialization without initializing firebase, is that posible?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have firebase already initialized in my app.module.ts with the config and all of that, and im going to use fireSQL to get items from my database because i like mySQL code to make this things, but the problem is that the [page about fireSQL  on firebaseopensource.com](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/jsayol/firesql/) says that you have to declare fireSQL like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp({config});
const fireSQL = new FireSQL(firebase.firestore());
```

And i dont want to do this, initialize here firebase again, is there a way to change "firebase.firestore()" to something that takes the already initialized firebase?

EDIT: another solution for my problem would be knowing how to do this query in firebase query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . ITEMS_TABLE . " WHERE (category LIKE '%".$category."%' AND (title LIKE '%" . $text . "%' OR description LIKE '%" . $text . "%')) ORDER BY ".$orderby." ".$ascdesc;
```

It's in PHP, not typescript because is from another project that i m transforming to angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `new FireSQL(...)` takes any instance of `Firestore`. When you do call `new FireSQL(firebase.firestore())` it creates **or gets** the Firestore object fro the default `FirebaseApp` object. So if you've previously created a default (unnamed) `FirebaseApp`, the `firebase.firestore()` code will retrieve the Firestore service from *that* same object.

If you have another non-default instance `FirebaseApp` or `Firestore` already, you can pass in in to `FireSQL` like this: `new FireSQL(myApp.firestore())` or `new FireSQL(myFirestore)`.

---

You won't be able to run an exact equivalent of that query on Firestore, because Firestore doesn't support `title LIKE '%" . $text` clauses. See:

- [Google Firestore: Query on substring of a property value (text search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search)
- [SQL LIKE operator in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645690)
- [Firestore Search - LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285039/firestore-search-like)

Comment: im gonna try that, but im having problems with the queries (i was trying fireSQL puting the config there to see how it is) its not possible to use LIKE %value% in fireSQL, so i'll have problems.

Comment: do u know how to do the query i posted in mySQL code into firebase query?

Comment: I added a section to my answer for that. Note that on Stack Overflow you should limit yourself to one question per post, as it increases the chances someone can help, and decreases the chance that your post will get closed/downvoted.

Comment: im struggeling so much with the query, how would the query be if u change the "like %value%" to "value%"?

Comment: The questions I linked show examples of that. If you're having a hard time making that work for your case, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).